# Book or series about boy with powers

Tags: story-identification

The protagonist of this book is a teenage boy. If my memory serves, the cover *might* have featured a phoenix in a ring, but that's just what I seem to remember. The story is set in a world that is basically the same as ours—contemporary times, social media, big cities, etc. But the main difference between our two worlds is that in the story, there are a number of people who possess powers. Some people are born with powers, and others are not. The world has a love-hate relationship with these people; some people adore and even hero-worship them, while many others hate or fear them. There is a government agency that uses various magical devices to control and oppress those with powers.

The protagonist is a teenage boy; he was adopted and lives with his adopted parents and brother in a large city. His brother is a fanatic, obsessed with those born with powers. The protagonist, who is gay, comes to work at a museum dedicated to phoenixes. One day, he discovers that he has powers—something none of his family or he had known (again, if my memory serves). His particular powers involve the use of fire. As he comes to discover his new identity, he and his family become entangled in the dangerous world of powers. He gets captured once, then escapes, and finds refuge with a group of people who like him possess powers.

Could someone tell me what this is?

Comment: Hmm... probably not https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12486724-phoenix-rising

Comment: So, if there's social media then the story must have been relatively recent, yes?  When did you read this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Infinity Son](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B07QLDWQDM/ref=cm_cr_arp_mb_bdcrb_top?ie=UTF8), by Adam Silvera.

The duotagonist Emil is gay and works in a phoenix museum gift shop

> Growing up in New York, brothers Emil and Brighton always idolized the Spell Walkers—a vigilante group sworn to rid the world of specters. While the Spell Walkers and other celestials are born with powers, specters take them, violently stealing the essence of endangered magical creatures.
>
> Brighton wishes he had a power so he could join the fray. Emil just wants the fighting to stop. The cycle of violence has taken a toll, making it harder for anyone with a power to live peacefully and openly. In this climate of fear, a gang of specters has been growing bolder by the day.

Comment: *"Brighton’s brother, Emil, is happier out of the limelight his brother craves. He works at a museum gift shop, hoping soon to be moved to a department specialising in phoenix history and preservation. Magical creatures such as these are threatened by the ambitions of the specters who hunt them for blood and body parts to add to potions that enable or increase their powers."*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry -> ["YA fantasy novel" and "phoenixes" and "gay"]

Comment: so are you saying...Google?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - yep. I've never read it.